# StackOverFlowError when looping through options

Tags: java, stack-overflow

I'm working on an exercise and I'm running into something. The following code gives me a stackoverflow error, but I have no idea why because my code should stop.

```
class Options {
    private int amount;
    private ArrayList<Integer> pieces;

    public void execute() {
        pieces = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        pieces.add(5);
        pieces.add(2);
        pieces.add(3);
        amount = pieces.size();
        combinations(new StringBuilder());
    }

    public void combinations(StringBuilder current) {
        if(current.length() == pieces.size()) {
            System.out.println(current.toString());
            return; 
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
            current.append(pieces.get(i));
            combinations(current);
        }
    }
}
```

It only prints the first output (555).

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Add a return to end your recursion

```
public void combinations(StringBuilder current) {
    if(current.length() == pieces.size()) {
        System.out.println(current.toString());
        return; // <-- like so.
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
        current.append(pieces.get(i));
        combinations(current);
    }
}
```

or put the loop in an `else` like

```
public void combinations(StringBuilder current) {
    if(current.length() == pieces.size()) {
        System.out.println(current.toString());
    } else {
        for(int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
            current.append(pieces.get(i));
            combinations(current);
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**

```
static class Options {
    private List<Integer> pieces;

    public void execute() {
        pieces = new ArrayList<>();
        pieces.add(5);
        pieces.add(2);
        pieces.add(3);
        combinations(new StringBuilder());
    }

    public void combinations(StringBuilder current) {
        if (current.length() == pieces.size()) {
            System.out.println(current.toString());
        } else {
            for (int i = current.length(); i < pieces.size(); i++) {
                current.append(pieces.get(i));
                combinations(current);
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Options o = new Options();
    o.execute();
    System.out.println(o.pieces);
}
```

Output is

```
523
[5, 2, 3]
```

Comment: @BartWesselink Doesn't throw `StackOverFlowError` anymore, does it?

Comment: Unfortunately, it still does.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError

Comment: @BartWesselink Edited. You're going to have to be more specific if you need more help.

Comment: The example you gave doesn't throw an error... I'll just try. Thanks